# How to use twilio and twiml to record a call and redirect the call or join someone else to the call

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-twiml

Hi im trying with node to receive a call, start recording the call and join someone else to the call (also tried redirect) and maintain the call recording. all this have been without success.

i tried

```
twiml.say('HI, Your Calling XXXXX, ');
twiml.dial("XXXXXXX");
twiml.record();
```

but when the dial command is used the record command doesn't work, if i comment the dial command, the call get recorded.

pleas hope you can help me find how i can record and redirect a call and while keep recording it

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Using `<Record>` only records one leg of a call and is mostly used for voicemail style operations.

To [record inbound calls with Twilio you need to use the Call Recordings API](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010317333-Recording-Incoming-Twilio-Voice-Calls) to trigger the recording to start.

**Note, you need to have upgraded your account to trigger recordings like this.**

You can trigger this API call as soon as you receive the inbound webhook. You can see [the documentation for the call recording resource here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording#create-a-recording-resource). If you were writing this in Node.js using Express, your route might look like this:

```js
// Load your Account Sid and Auth Token somehow, for example, from the environment
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const twilio = require('twilio')
const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);

app.post('/calls', (req, res) => {
  const callSid = req.body.CallSid;

  client.calls(callSid)
      .recordings
      .create()
      .then(recording => console.log('Recording started')
      .catch(err => console.error('Recording failed. ', err);

  const twiml = new twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  const numberToDial = process.env.NUMBER_TO_DIAL;
  twiml.say(`Hi, you're calling ${numberToDial}.`);
  twiml.dial(numberToDial);
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  res.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

Let me know if that helps at all.